# ASP.NET MVC View not rendering with layout after form post using angular

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, forms, post, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm routing the views using **ngRoute** and not having any particular issues rendering most views. The only problem I am having is when I do a post method and passing a list to the view.

Site/Page renders the view with no layout. 
Typing into the address bar http://localhost:7351/Page works and provides layout but obviously no View. If I post the form in http://localhost:7351/Main the browser URL changes to http://localhost:7351/Site/Page and displays the results without any layout.

Form in view **Main**

```
<form method="post" action="Site/Page">
   <input id="chk_main" type="checkbox" />
   <input type=submit>
</form>
```

**RouteConfig**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Page",
    url: "Site/Page",
    defaults: new { controller = "Site", action = "Page" }
);
```

**EDIT:** If I change "url: Site/Page" to "url: Page" the Layout will show, but then View won't.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult Main()
{
    return View(persons);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Page()
{
    return View();
}
```

**Angular Route Provider:**

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/Main', {
        templateUrl: 'Site/Main'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'Site/Contact'
    })
    .when('/Page', {
        templateUrl: 'Site/Page'
    })
```

Is there something that i'm missing or don't understand.

Comment: How does your View actually look like? Do you have a `_ViewStart.cshtml` page?

Comment: No I don't have that I'll edit and add the view I'm trying to render

Comment: When you access the `/Site/Main` (for example) normally using the location bar, does the Layout being included?

Comment: yeah, all other views do include the layout